# Get selected value of a dropdown's using jquery php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a drop down

```
  <div class="form-group">
 <select class="form-control" required name="uname" id="uname">
 <option value=""/>Select Your Name</option>
  <?php foreach ($this->getallusers as $users): ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $users['adminID'] ?>"<?= $users['adminID'] == $stories['Tm_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>/><?php echo $users['UserName'] ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Drop down have values.then when i am tried to get the selected drop down value from jquery.

```
var op=$('#uname option :selected').text(); 
 var opid=$('#uname option :selected').val(); alert(opid);
```

When i alert `op`(text) i always got **Select Your Name** and opid is always blank.but drop down i have values pakka.Any help would be Appreciated .

Comment: note, you are closing your `option` opening tag -> `<option value=".." />...</option>`, as you have `/>` between `<?= $users['adminID'] == $stories['Tm_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>` and `<?php echo $users['UserName'] ?>`

Comment: @Sean can you please text it as answer

Answer (score 1):

try to use just this code:

```
alert($("#uname").val());
```

////////

.val() - gets a value of any input and dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get the currently selected value and text when `select` box is change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#uname").change(function(){
        var op = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
        var opid = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        alert("You have selected - " + op + " -> " opid);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space from `option` and `:selected` on your `jquery`. So intead of

```
var op=$('#uname option :selected').text(); 
var opid=$('#uname option :selected').val(); alert(opid);
```

it should be

```
var op=$('#uname option:selected').text(); 
var opid=$('#uname option:selected').val(); alert(opid);
```